# Is this.props immutable?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` is called when a component is receiving new props.  And the idea is, I'll set some state or do something based on these new props.  And my initial expectation is that `this.props` will get set to `newProps` after this method finishes, but this seems to not be the case.  It seems that the `this.props` object is never changed.

So it's fair to conclude that `this.props` is immutable?

Comment: `this.props` is changed and the new value is immediately available in `render()` method.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was a mistake somewhere else I didn't notice.  With all the immutability talk surrounding react and js in general, I was just itching for this.props to be immutable!

Comment: Immutability does not mean the thing cannot be *replaced* (entirely) though.

Comment: True, was confusing with a final variable.  So in this case by having `this.props` immutable I'm guessing the main performance benefit is to be able to rely on referential equality? Or is this.props mutable?

Comment: Well, react itself does not mutate it (I'm not a react contributor so I cannot guarantee that, I haven't seen it ever though).